# Links in Table not detected by screen reader

Tags: html, accessibility

I have a link button in my code where if it's focused by tabbing or clicking, a div will come down. I'm able to focus child table elements (the a href building inside td . See child code) using tab but screen reader is not providing audio feedback of the link.

Button code:

```
 <a
      tabindex="0"
      class="button dropdown secondary status_button"
      id="twh-dd-anchor2"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="thisweek-dropdown2"
      data-closable=""
      aria-controls="thisweek-dropdown2"
      data-is-focus="false"
      data-yeti-box="thisweek-dropdown2"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false"
      >Building Status</a
    >
```

Page that pops up on button click:

```
<div
  class="dropdown-pane is-open has-position-bottom has-alignment-right"
  id="thisweek-dropdown2"
  aria-labelledby="twh-dd-anchor2"
  data-dropdown=""
  data-hover="true"
  data-hover-pane="true"
  aria-hidden="true"
  data-yeti-box="thisweek-dropdown2"
  data-resize="thisweek-dropdown2"
  data-n="u4ighp-n"
  data-events="resize"
  style="top: 78.1797px; left: -226.719px"
>
  <table class="quick-link-list unstriped">
    <thead class="show-for-sr">
      <tr>
        <th>Space/Service</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/about/spaces/building" role="link"> Building</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: also an <a> without a <href> isn't a "real" anchor/link, it's essentially just a span as far as screenreaders - and keyboard navigation - is concerned. You shouldn't use this element if it's not actually intended to navigate to a new page. (If it's there to trigger some onpage action, like for example revealing/hiding some content, it should be a button element.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your data attributes on your child div, you set:
aria-hidden="true"

That is going to prevent screen readers from reading out what's inside this div.

As soon as I removed that I used NVDA and could hear it read out "Building".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden

Comment: I had to set the attribute of aria-hidden to false when the button is focused  on tab. Hard coding aria-hidden to false for some reason wouldn't work so I had to make changes in javascript. Thank you, Dean Miranda for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: You must remove aria-hidden attribute entirely to make sure screen readers can read it. aria-hidden=false is sometimes taken the same as ria-hidden=true. Additionally, you have no reason to switch aria-hidden depending on tab focus, as there are other means to navigate with a screen readers than tab and the content won't be read in that cases. Aria-hidden shouldn't be present at all.